# How to return JSON using plumber api in R

Tags: json, r, plumber

I am new to R . I am supposed to expose rest service using R , So i found plumber to expose rest service using R , 
I Successfully implemented plumber in R , but in response i am receiving a json array like below

> [{"name":"Rajesh","age":"10"}]

how to remove the array from the above response

my expected output is like below

> {"name":"Rajesh","age":"10"}

Code

```
 library(plumber)
r <- plumb("MyFile.R")
r$run(port=8000)
```

My File .R is mentioned below

```
    #* @post /sum
addTwo <- function(){
  name<-c("Rajesh")
  age<-c("10")
  df<-data.frame(name,age)

  return(df)

}
```

Comment: `df <- jsonlite::unbox(data.frame(name, age))`

Comment: Plumber output serialization with json is documented in https://www.rplumber.io/articles/rendering-output.html

Answer (score 1):

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(name, age, auto_unbox=TRUE))
```

Comment: `auto_unbox` argument is inside the wrong bracket, and I don't think this answers the question

Comment: you're probably right. i'll know more by this evening.

Comment: Seems, there was no final answer posted. @Rajesh did you figure out yourself? If yes could you care to close this question with the solution as I have the same question too? Thanks.